# Which is correct `in the team` or `on the team`

Tags: prepositions

> I have yet to discuss this with someone *in the team* / *on the team*

Which one of these is correct?

The text was autocorrected by software from "*in the team*" to "*on the team*".

Comment: What service or app did the autocorrecting?

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence about membership (someone's relationship to a team) "on" is the preposition to use. The word "on" is used to indicate physical location but also membership in an organization.

*He is on the board of directors (he is a member).*

*He is on the school's baseball and track teams.*

However, there are also expressions that use "in" to describe a role, a position, or membership in an organization or hierarchy:

*He is in the fraternity.*

*She is in the legislative branch of government.*

*His position is in the C-suite of a global corporation.*